# Magento 2 isn't generating my pub images

Tags: magento2

I was running into an issue that my Magento 2 instance wasn't generating images on my Windows 7 machine. The system wasn't producing any errors and it had all installed perfectly. I also was meeting all requirements for installation and no files were modified. I was running Magento 2 0.42.0-beta9 on Apache 2.4.2, PHP 5.5.22, MySQL 5.6.6.

[image: Magento 2 beta not showing images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a RewriteBase to my /pub/static/.htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteBase /magento/2b/pub/static/
```

My magento was located at www.example.com/magento/2b/ so my base was "/magento/2b/". Here's how it looked after the modification:
[image]

Hopefully this helps someone out there!

Comment: sounds like you modified the .htaccess rules in /pub, it should run fine with the default .htaccess files.

Comment: No, I actually didn't - that's the off thing. I had to add the rewrite base line to make it work.

Comment: Had the same problem with latest with version 2.1.6. Had to add a Rebase in root .htaccess and a rebase in static .htaccess. There seems to be an issue with using alias and rewrite on Debian. At least I think so. I ended up to this when moving my local Magento instance from local root to an alias on the server.